How much latency does the operating system add transferring video over USB to the host application?
I am transferring raw uncompressed video from an image sensor to a C++ OpenCV application running on Linux. The signal chain is this:
MIPI output Image sensor -> MIPI to USB 3.0 chip -> USB 3.0 Hub chip -> USB port on PC -> Application code.
I know roughly how much latency is added by the first 3 steps, up to the USB port on the PC. However, I'm not sure how much latency is likely to be added by the software.
Questions:
Once a frame of video is fully transferred to the PC, roughly how long before it's available to the application software?
Will Linux or OpenCV buffer multiple frames, or will each frame be available to the application very soon after it arrives?
Does anyone have any actual measurements of the latency?
Added: I'd be happy to have an answer in terms of a likely range in units frame intervals. For example, possible answers might be: "There's probably no multi-frame buffering, and the latency will be an insignificant fraction of a frame interval." or "I've seen a similar setup buffer a couple of frames, and so you may get a latency of 1 - 2 frames on a 50 FPS video."

did you measure this? assuming no, how would you measure this in your setup? does your host have GPIO capability so you can scope/LA the situation? what do you know about the host-side APIs and drivers?

I have not attempted to measure it, and I know nothing about the drivers etc. That's why I'm asking. Perhaps other people have come across this problem and have some wisdom for me. In theory I could measure the latency of the image to the screen (using photodiodes), which presumably is slightly longer than the latency just to the application. I don't have any easy GPIO at the host that I know is very low latency. (I remember the good old days when the parallel port was accessible with a low latency OUT instruction to address 0x378.

To the people voting to close, please could you state why, so that I may improve the question?

for me, it's a combination of things. first, several things aren't pinned down, such the application code, how it talks to USB, custom comms or something based on USB UVC, which USB transfer modes are involved, ... then, none of us can actually debug this (no "MRE"). best you can hope for is anecdotes/opinions, but nobody can  guarantee with documentation/specs that your situation could be the same as anyone else's. sure I could say "ideally and theoretically here are the absolute minimum sources of latency, and there is how all kinds of substandard implementations could add more latency"

What format are the images during transfer? Is it already BGR pixel bitmap? Is it encoded with a processing heavy encoder? A simple way to measure full latency (including rendering) is to capture a microsecond-resolution timer on your screen and display the captured video live on your screen. Then take a screenshot and read out the difference of the timer and the displayed capture. But that one includes the latency of rendering ;)

specific example: you tagged OpenCV. what code do you currently use to get your images "into OpenCV"? cv::VideoCapture? what backend/API? if you don't, but your comms are entirely custom based on libusb or whatever, then OpenCV doesn't even matter. -- this question has too many moving parts. it's an engineering task to figure out where your latencies show up.

if your host has no GPIO, at least it has USB, so you could send back down a notification of when you received a frame. then your device can at least know the roundtrip time including USB, libusb, and OS scheduler. latencies due to USB itself should be on the order of 1 ms or 1/8 ms for USB 2.0 anyway (IDK what USB grants you). you'd measure time from transmission to reception of confirmation, on the device. that still won't tell you where it's all spent, but if it's small enough, and mostly explainable from theoretical figuring, you might not even care to dig deeper.

details on the USB comms (all the chips) and used APIs hostside (V4L? plain libusb?) would be helpful.

@ChristophRackwitz - Thanks for your comments. I actually don't know the answers to some of your questions. I'm using a fairly standard Ubuntu installation. I haven't tried to do anything clever here. I've just got a raw video stream coming in on USB 3.0, and I'm picking it up in an OpenCV application. I haven't changed any drivers. Would the specific chipset actually affect the latency of the frame inside the host? (I'm asking this out of ignorance).

so... just VideoCapture(0) or VideoCapture("/dev/video0") without any specific choice of backend/API? then your video chip seems to act as a USB UVC device. -- hostside is hostside. I doubt the chip could affect anything over there.  the chip itself could buffer but that's unlikely to be an entire frame, probably way less (a line or a few). there's also no reason why the hostside USB stack or V4L driver should delay a frame once it's all there. you might get latency from misbehaving device drivers that hog the CPU for longer than they should (which is why "realtime linux" is a thing)

@Micka - It's a raw uncompressed monochrome image. There's no encoding or anything. I can certainly measure the latency to the screen optically, as you say. But I'm more interested in measuring it to the application.

@ChristophRackwitz - Yes, I'm just using VideoCapture(0). I could in theory send a USB packet back down, but this is outside my field of expertise.

if the application were a pure information sink, any latency to it wouldn't matter. what information does it emit and what systems wait for this information? can you use the same channel to measure the latency?

@ChristophRackwitz - There are probably ways I could set up a measurement. I just thought that there might be people out there with experience in this field who could share their wisdom. I can't be the first person to wonder about the latency of video for machine vision applications.

the one source of latency you can expect is the display(ing). there may be a frame of latency or more in everything from you issuing any kind of drawing command to an actual pixel on the display changing its state. generic desktop graphics aren't optimized for latency, imshow and waitKey aren't usually. if you care about that side, you'll have to look into graphics APIs (games care about latency) -- other usual sources of latency are any kind of video compression. you don't have that though. this can be dumb old MJPEG compression that has been present in USB 2 webcams for decades so far.
